# Get multiple URL of attachments from a column in Google Sheet and mail using Appscripts

Tags: google-apps-script

I have made a program to send mails whenever a user fills in a Google form.
However, while the mail is going, the script is not picking the attachments from the column which are separated using commas.

The column has values like this(sample) - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JBnVvwYmB1DZp01vP1eeve4yg86KOKmc, https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JBnVvwYmB1DZp01vP1eeve4yg86KOKmc, https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JBnVvwYmB1DZp01vP1eeve4yg86KOKmc

I saw an example that uses YAMM addon and does this, but I'd be glad if someone can offer me the solution as I do not want to rely on the add-on.
Sharing code.

```js
function ifstatement() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses");

  var Avals = ss.getRange("b1:b").getValues();
  var lr = Avals.filter(String).length;

  Logger.log(lr);

  var heading = ws.getRange(lr,17).getValue();
  var subheading = ws.getRange(lr,4).getValue();
  var body = ws.getRange(lr,11).getValue();
  var footer = ws.getRange(lr,12).getValue();
  var impfield1 = ws.getRange(lr,5).getValue();
  var impfield2 = ws.getRange(lr,7).getValue();
  var impfield3 = ws.getRange(lr,9).getValue();
  var fieldvalue1 = ws.getRange(lr,6).getValue();
  var fieldvalue2 = ws.getRange(lr,8).getValue();
  var fieldvalue3 = ws.getRange(lr,10).getValue();
  var attach = ws.getRange(lr, 18).getValue();
  var file1 = [UrlFetchApp.fetch(attach).getBlob()]
  var sub = ws.getRange(lr,3).getValue();
Logger.log(attach)

  var mailtemp = ws.getRange(lr,2).getValue();


  if(mailtemp=="HTML1"){
    const htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Copy of HTML1");
    htmlTemplate.heading = heading;
    htmlTemplate.subheading = subheading;
    htmlTemplate.body = body;
    htmlTemplate.footer = footer;
    htmlTemplate.impfield1 = impfield1;
    htmlTemplate.impfield2 = impfield2;
    htmlTemplate.impfield3 = impfield3;
    htmlTemplate.fieldvalue1 = fieldvalue1;
    htmlTemplate.fieldvalue2 = fieldvalue2;
    htmlTemplate.fieldvalue3 = fieldvalue3;

    const htmlforemail = htmlTemplate.evaluate().getContent();

    GmailApp.sendEmail("mayank.agarwal@aumcap.com",
    "Issue closes tomorrow - Invest in SGB scheme today!",
    "Last chance to invest in SGB scheme issue I",
    {htmlBody: htmlforemail,
    attachments: file1}
    ) } else if(lr=="HTML2"){
          const htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("SGB I");
          htmlTemplate.heading = heading;
          htmlTemplate.subheading = subheading;
          htmlTemplate.body = body;
          htmlTemplate.footer = footer;
          htmlTemplate.impfield1 = impfield1;
          htmlTemplate.impfield2 = impfield2;
          htmlTemplate.impfield3 = impfield3;
          htmlTemplate.fieldvalue1 = fieldvalue1;
          htmlTemplate.fieldvalue2 = fieldvalue2;
          htmlTemplate.fieldvalue3 = fieldvalue3;

          const htmlforemail = htmlTemplate.evaluate().getContent();

          GmailApp.sendEmail("mayank.agarwal@aumcap.com",
          "Issue closes tomorrow - Invest in SGB scheme today!",
          "Last chance to invest in SGB scheme issue I",
          {htmlBody: htmlforemail,
          attachments: file1}
          )
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- In your situation, the following URLs are put in one cell of `var attach = ws.getRange(lr, 18).getValue()`. You want to retrieve the blob data from those files.

  - `https://drive.google.com/open?id=###, https://drive.google.com/open?id=###, https://drive.google.com/open?id=###`

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var file1 = [UrlFetchApp.fetch(attach).getBlob()]
```

#### To:

```
var file1 = attach.split(",").map(url => DriveApp.getFileById(url.trim().split("=")[1]).getBlob());
```

- In this modification, those URLs separated by `,` are splitted by `,` and each blob is retrieved with `DriveApp.getFileById()`.

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [getFileById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfilebyidid)

Comment: I am so so thankful to you.
Can you please explain to me the logic of file1 in more detail?
What does the split("=")[1] do?
This is just for my learning purpose :)

Comment: @Mayank Agarwal Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `split("=")[1]`, in this case, `###` from `https://drive.google.com/open?id=###` by splitting the URL by `=`. By this, the file ID is retrieved. If this explanation is not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks understood! And what is the [1] part?

Comment: @Mayank Agarwal Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. About `And what is the [1] part?`, when `split("=")` is run for `https://drive.google.com/open?id=###`, an array like `["https://drive.google.com/open?id", "###"]` is returned. `[1]` is the 2nd element of `"###"`. [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: Understood! Thanks Tanaike.